# AVFoundation adjusting white balance while focus is close up and background (out-of-focus) is dark

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

Can anyone please point me in the correct direction or tell me if what I am trying to do is simply not possible?

I'm trying to take a picture of something close up.  I am able to lock the focus.  That works well.  We have found that keeping the torch on while trying to focus and take the picture works best.  The issue I cannot seem to resolve is the white balance.  If the background is dark, the object I'm trying to focus on is too light.  Is there a trick to adjusting the white balance when the item in focus is close up and the background (out of focus) is dark?

I can't provide the code, it's too much.  I suppose if necessary I could create a sample project, but my question is probably more conceptual.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, for those who run across the same issue, is to use a CALayer for an exposeBox and another CALayer for a focusBox.  That appeared to do the trick.  Of course, I would still like to hear of solutions from others and I'm still curious about controlling the aperture.

Thank you.